# deadlock found on MySql5.0 but not found after MySql5.6

Tags: mysql, deadlock

```
CREATE TABLE 'test'.'t1' (
  'id' INT NULL);
CREATE TABLE 'test'.'t2' (
  'id' INT NULL);

INSERT INTO test.t1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO test.t2 VALUES(1);
```

### example1:

sqlConnection1:

```
    SET autocommit = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE test.t1 set id = 1 WHERE id = 2;
```

sqlConnection2:

```
    SET autocommit = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    LOCK TABLES test.t2 WRITE,test.t1 WRITE;
    COMMIT;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
```

sqlConnection1:

```
    UPDATE test.t2 set id = 1 where id = 2;
    COMMIT;
```

sqlConnection2:

```
    ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restart transaction
```

### example2:

sqlConnection1:

```
    SET autocommit = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE test.t1 set id = 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

sqlConnection2:

```
    SET autocommit = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    LOCK TABLES test.t2 WRITE,test.t1 WRITE;
    COMMIT;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
```

sqlConnection1:

```
    UPDATE test.t2 set id = 1 where id = 1;
    COMMIT;
```

sqlConnection1:

```
    ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restart transaction
```

### example3:

deadlock not found after mysql5.6

### question:

What causes the results to differ in three examples

Comment: I think it means mysql guys fix some bug on their transaction implementation. because it's hard to get transaction right. open source db make mistakes very ofen, You don't want to pay? so this is what you have to bear with..

Comment: Even the support for 5.6 ends february 2021...time to update I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

There are several points in this problem.

1. When InnoDB tries to update a record it will put a *RECORD LOCK* or a *GAP LOCK* onto the range it is going to update. For records that are existent, InnoDB will put a record lock, otherwise a gap lock. For example, in example 1, InnoDB will add a gap lock, and in this case, it adds a [2,∞) gap lock onto the table.
2. MySQL's `LOCK TABLES` command actually implements in MySQL itself but not in InnoDB. Although MySQL's `LOCK TABLE` has a "deadlock-free design" in other table-lock-only storage engines like MyISAM, it cannot avoid the deadlocks in InnoDB since InnoDB has row-level locks. Fortunately, the InnoDB has a deadlock detection mechanism that can detect when an InnoDB row lock and a MySQL table lock occur together on the same table and do what you see -- rollback a "lighter" transaction to avoid deadlock, which is so-called "victim".
3. The InnoDB engine will generally decide the transaction with fewer rows affected to be the victim. In example 1, connection 1 puts two *GAP LOCKS* on rows [2,∞) for two tables, while connection 2 only acquires two *WRITE LOCKS* and does not get anything done. Thus, connection 2 is "lighter" and being selected as the "victim". In example 2, connection 1 only has two *RECORD LOCKS* while connection 2 still has two *WRITE LOCKS*, and connection 1 basically do not do anything. Thus InnoDB decides that connection 1 uses fewer resources (i.e. locks in this case), and chooses connection 1 as the victim.
4. Since MySQL 5.6, a new lock wait mechanism has been introduced to MySQL. When MySQL cannot acquire a table lock, it will wait as long as the interval `lock-wait-timeout` specified. quote from the MySQL document:

> This variable[lock-wait-timeout] specifies the timeout in seconds for attempts to acquire metadata locks. The permissible values range from 1 to 31536000 (1 year). The default is 31536000.
> This timeout applies to all statements that use metadata locks. These include DML and DDL operations on tables, views, stored procedures, and stored functions, as well as LOCK TABLES, FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK, and HANDLER statements.

Thus, MySQL will not acquire a table lock when it sees InnoDB already has a lock on the table it is going to manipulate and wait until InnoDB gets its work done. For further information, you can refer to MySQL document(The following documents are for 8.0 version, but the basic principles are the same):
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html